# Resize GameObject over time

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, 2d, scale

Excuse me for any grammatical errors.

I'm trying to gradually resize an object and I know how to do this but i'm having some troubles on the scale check, let me explain it better..

I'm using this code to resize the object :

```
 IEnumerator makeObjSmaller()
 {
     while (transform.localScale != new Vector3 (0.15F, 0.15F, 0.15F)) {
         transform.localScale -= new Vector3 (0.01F, 0.01F, 0.01F);
             yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.001f);
     }
 }
```

The problem here is that the scale will never be equals to (0.15F, 0.15F, 0.15F), I don't know why but after about 10 cicles the scale becomes equal to something like "x.xyzabc" (letters simply are variables).

Assuming that the initial value of the object's scale is (40, 40, 40), during the while cicle it should become something like ( 39.99, 39.98 ... 0.06, 0.05) so only two digits after the comma not 6, it will become something like (0.059584) that's not equal to (0.05).

Comment: Do you know the value you want to resize it into? You want to go from the current size to that size over time?

Comment: Yes, I said it, the initial size is (40, 40, 40) the final size should be (0.15, 0.15, 0.15).

Comment: See duplicate..

Comment: @Programmer thank you, I searched for duplicates before posting it but I didn't find that post!